# Object mapper class for multiple keyspaces in Cassandra DB

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

I'm using the datastax-java-driver for cassandra to use an Object Mapper to access the data in a table, as explained [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/manual/object_mapper/creating/).
The issue I have is that I want this mapped class to work in two different keyspaces (say prod and test, where the tables being mapped have the same structure) but the keyspace is one of the `@Table` annotation attributes so I can't change it programmatically accordingly, i.e. it has to be defined statically at compile time.

Is there a way to use a mapped class in two different keyspaces? I'm using cassandra-driver-mapping v2.1.10.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just Don't set the `keyspace` element on `@Table` Annotation**

In `@Table` only the name Element is the mandatory, all the other element are optional. If you don't set the keyspace name then session's connected keyspace will be used.

Example :

```
@Table(name = "users")
public static class User {
    @PartitionKey
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private UUID userId;
    private String name;
    // ... constructors / getters / setters
}
```

Source : http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/mapping/annotations/Table.html